# Will 2000A Inrush Current Damage Outlet Circuitry?

Tags: voltage, current, ac, outlet

First time building an AC control system complete with motors, PLC, sensors, power supplies. All this is sourced from a 220VAC outlet. I have calculated the total current draw of all motors, powers supplies, etc, to be about 38A at full load. What I am concerned about is my 2000A inrush current calculation. Would it be safe to enable the 220VAC line to the control system when connected to a 220VAC wall outlet that can output 60A? Is this kind of inrush current value normal for industrial control systems, therefore it is alright and outlet circuitry can safely handle this event?

Comment: Show calculations and assumptions.  What does I^2R tell you with R= source + load  impedance. Or ratio of R for source/load?  Also consider inductance with cable at 1 uH/m

Comment: I don't think you can get 2000A of inrush current, and it would probably trip most breakers, you'd have to have a 2000A breaker.

Comment: 2 servo drives (main circuit) - 44A inrush each

Comment: 30 power supplies - 60A each,
1 PLC rack - 12A inrush

Comment: 2 servo drives (control circuit) - 32A each

Comment: This information is from manufacturer datasheets

Comment: You can edit your question to include these infos on the question, not on comments. Its easier to follow for future readers.

Comment: Noted, thank you for the patience.

Answer (score 1):

In general, a 60 amp branch circuit should be constructed using components; conductors, connectors, and outlet devices that will be protected by a 60 amp circuit breaker of a type that is suitable for that service. All branch circuit components should be certified by an independent testing laboratory in that regard. The standards that apply to the distribution components should tell you what they can withstand. It may be easier to examine the curve for the circuit breaker. If the worst-case instance of short term current will not trip the circuit breaker, the distribution components should be ok.